# Android RecyclerView not showing the right xml

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm trying to use a RecyclerView to show a horizontal list of contacts. I spend hours to find my error and I really don't understand why this keep happening. My application is a Tinder-like.

**My row item :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_conversation_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="4pt"
        tool:text="Name Name"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_conversation_avatar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/photo1"
        android:layout_above="@id/tv_conversation_name"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[This is what happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWxGu.png)

[I did a layout like this one in a other fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8Psj.png)

**My adapter :**

```
public class ConversationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConversationAdapter.ConversationViewHolder>{
    private List<Conversation> conversationList = new ArrayList<>();

    public class ConversationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public ImageView avatar;

        ConversationViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_conversation_name);
            avatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_conversation_avatar);
        }
    }

    public ConversationAdapter(List<Conversation> conversationList) {
        this.conversationList = conversationList;
    }

    @Override
    public ConversationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_conversation, parent, false);
        return new ConversationViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ConversationViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Conversation conversation = conversationList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(conversation.getName());

        byte[] decodedByteArray = android.util.Base64.decode(conversation.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        holder.avatar.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByteArray, 0, decodedByteArray.length));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return conversationList.size();
    }
}
```

**How I configure my RecyclerView :**

```
conversationAdapter = new ConversationAdapter(conversationList);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManagerHorizontal = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
rvConversation.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManagerHorizontal);
rvConversation.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
rvConversation.setAdapter(conversationAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the width and height of the RelativeLayout in your row item file is only 80dp, which I don't think is what you want here. Try setting these values to "match_parent", like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_margin="8dp">
```

Or use "wrap_content", depending on the look you are trying to achieve.